# How to change width and height of Container in plantUml (c4)

Tags: plantuml

I have the following example in plantUml from github:

```
    @startuml "messagebus"
!include https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plantuml-stdlib/C4-PlantUML/master/C4_Container.puml
' uncomment the following line and comment the first to use locally
' !include C4_Container.puml

AddElementTag("microService", $shape=EightSidedShape(), $bgColor="CornflowerBlue", $fontColor="white", $legendText="micro service\neight sided")
AddElementTag("storage", $shape=RoundedBoxShape(), $bgColor="lightSkyBlue", $fontColor="white")

Person(customer, Customer, "A customer")

System_Boundary(c1, "Customer Information") {
    Container(app, "Customer Application", "Javascript, Angular", "Allows customers to manage their profile")
    Container(customer_service, "Customer Service", "Java, Spring Boot", "The point of access for customer information", $tags = "microService")
    Container(message_bus, "Message Bus", "RabbitMQ", "Transport for business events")
    Container(reporting_service, "Reporting Service", "Ruby", "Creates normalised data for reporting purposes", $tags = "microService")
    Container(audit_service, "Audit Service", "C#/.NET", "Provides organisation-wide auditing facilities", $tags = "microService")
    ContainerDb(customer_db, "Customer Database", "Oracle 12c", "Stores customer information", $tags = "storage")
    ContainerDb(reporting_db, "Reporting Database", "MySQL", "Stores a normalized version of all business data for ad hoc reporting purposes", $tags = "storage")
    Container(audit_store, "Audit Store", "Event Store", "Stores information about events that have happened", $tags = "storage")
}

@enduml
```

How can I change the size of message_bus component ?